# Mocking window.location object

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have got an iFrame that I want to take the URL of in its src attribute and fetch its content and inject it into the iFrame with docuemnt.write. So now, the iFrame is in the same origin and I can touch its contentWindow.
But I'm having some trouble with a JS file running inside the iFrame that is using the window.location object and of course, in my current situation it's empty (no src for the iFrame). So, the code has some unexpected behaviour :(.
I think I have got 2 options here:

1. Wrap the JS code with an anonymous function and pass it our "proxied" 
   window object, like this:

   var windowProxy = {
               location : {
                   origin : "test",
                   search : "test"
               }
           };
           (function(window){
           console.log(window.location.origin);
           console.log(window.location.search);
           })(windowProxy);

That works, but I think I will have more errors with this method because everything is also executing in the function context. So if the code declaring global variables or anything like that change, then everything will be messed up, I think.

2. The secod approach and the most difficult to implement is to parse the JS and replace the call to window.location with window.fakelocation (with fakelocation as our faked window.location object).

I would really appreciate some advice or maybe other approaches. :)

UPDATE:
Well, I just realised that the first approach is impossible because I will have to create the entire window object and that’s ridiculous.

So, I'm left with the second approach for now. :(

Comment: You can push in a mock (https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) if you don't want to create it yourself. There are tons of people with the same problem. :)

Comment: @Caramiriel  I see it’s for node js , but other than that I will still have unexpected problems because the code will run inside the function context and not the global one